# Divisível - portugol (VISUALG)

Tags: algoritmo, portugol, visualg

Tenho a seguinte questão e em baixo o que já tentei mas ele não está mostrando apenas os números divisíveis que é a minha intenção.

Eu estou fazendo o teste digitando o número 8, o correto era pro programa dizer "**8 é divisível por 8 e por 2**"

Escreva um algoritmo que receba um número do teclado e informar se ele é divisível por 8, por 5, por 2 ou se não é divisível por nenhum destes. Verifique para cada um dos números.
Exemplo:
Número: 8
Divisível por 8

**Meu Código**

```
var 
numero,contador,divisivel: inteiro
inicio
 contador <- 1
 divisível<- 0
escreva("Digite um número: )
 leia(numero)
repita
 escreva(contador)
   se(numero % contador = 0) então
  divisível <- divisível + 1
fimse
  contador <- contador + 1
ate (contador > numero)
  escreva("Número: ",divisível)
fimalgoritimo
```

Comment: Tem como formatar melhor seu código?, de modo que não precise da imagem para entendê-lo?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu não consegui deixar como na imagem.
:(

Sou novato no stackoverflow.
Se você conseguir me ajudar na formatação do código eu agradeceria demais.
:)

Comment: No problema ele só pede para testar a divisibilidade por 2, 5 e 8, mas você fez o teste para contar quantos divisores tem um número; você fez mais que o problema pediu

Comment: enquanto eu escrevo a resposta, você pode dar uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Também tem uma seção na central de ajuda sobre [linguagem de marcação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado e como ficaria o código correto para divisibilidade apenas por 2,5 e 8?

Comment: Acabei de responder; no celular, minha digitação é mais lenta

Comment: Obrigado e desculpa!   Vou ver agora. Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Como eu não sei a sintaxe exata do portugol/visualg, peço a gentileza de corrigir qualquer deslize

Esse é um problema cuja resposta precisa atender a uma questão de decisão e, também, precisa atender a formatação de uma resposta.

> O que é uma questão de decisão?

Uma questão de decisão é um problema para o qual se deve responder `sim` ou `não`. Exemplos de problema de decisão:

- 9 é número quadrado?
- 10 é número quadrado?
- 8 é divisível por 5?
- 8 é divisível por 2?
- dado algoritmo [vai executar até encontrar uma resposta para todas as entradas possíveis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_parada?wprov=sfsi1)?

> Note que nem sempre é possível obter a resposta afirmativa ou negativa, mas isso é outra conversa para outro dia.

## Problema de decisão da questão

A questão pergunta se dado número é divisível por 8, se ele é divisível por 5 e por 2; pergunta isso individualmente, então, para 200, preciso responder que sim três vezes.

Cada uma dessas perguntas é uma instância de um problema maior: `X` é divisível por `Y`?

Para responder à questão geral, o código é:

```
X % Y = 0
```

Então, para cada uma das perguntas, substituo o `Y` pelo valor adequado:

```
X % 8 = 0
X % 5 = 0
X % 2 = 0
```

## Formatando a resposta

O formato da resposta é:

```
X é divisível por N( e por K)*
```

Onde `X` é o número informado, `N` é o primeiro divisor, e a parte entre parênteses se repete para cada `K` também divisor de `X`.

Para identificar se já foi detectado divisores do nosso universo de busca (8, 5, e 2, nessa ordem), vou usar uma variável chamada `divisores_encontrados`, que vai guardar o valor de quantos divisores o algoritmo achou até aquele instante. Isso significa que ela começa com zero e, caso alguma das verificações retorne que o número é divisor, incremento o valor de `divisores_encontrados`.

Observação: considere tudo depois da `#` como comentário

```
var entrada, divisores_encontrados, divisor_teste: inteiro
início 
    divisores_encontrados <- 0 # inicializando o valor; ainda não foi encontrado nada
    leia(entrada)

    divisor_teste <- 8
    se entrada % divisor_teste = 0 então 
        se divisores_encontrados = 0 # primeira vez que encontrou um divisor 
            escreva(entrada)
            escreva(" é divisível por ")
            escreva(divisor_teste)
        senão
            escreva(" e por ")
            escreva(divisor_teste)
        fimse # verificação do primeiro divisor encontrado
        divisores_encontrados <- divisores_encontrados + 1
    fimse # verificação da divisibilidade 

    divisor_teste <- 5
    se entrada % divisor_teste = 0 então 
        se divisores_encontrados = 0 # primeira vez que encontrou um divisor 
            escreva(entrada)
            escreva(" é divisível por ")
            escreva(divisor_teste)
        senão
            escreva(" e por ")
            escreva(divisor_teste)
        fimse # verificação do primeiro divisor encontrado
        divisores_encontrados <- divisores_encontrados + 1
    fimse # verificação da divisibilidade 

    divisor_teste <- 2
    se entrada % divisor_teste = 0 então 
        se divisores_encontrados = 0 # primeira vez que encontrou um divisor 
            escreva(entrada)
            escreva(" é divisível por ")
            escreva(divisor_teste)
        senão
            escreva(" e por ")
            escreva(divisor_teste)
        fimse # verificação do primeiro divisor encontrado
        divisores_encontrados <- divisores_encontrados + 1
    fimse # verificação da divisibilidade 

    se divisores_encontrados = 0 
        escreva(entrada)
        escreva(" não é divisível por 2, 5 e nem 8")
    fimse # caso sem divisibilidade por 2, 5, 8

    escreval("") # só para pular linha no fim ;-)
fimalgoritmo
```

## Bônus: Sobre a quantidade de divisores

Seu programa da pergunta calcula quantos divisores um número tem. Ele escreve a cada passo do laço qual número sendo testado, porém sem quebrar linha.

Você pode simplesmente não escrever esses números intermediários se eles não te interessam.

Para saber quantos divisores tem um número, também não precisamos passar por todos os números menores do que o número informado; existem estratégias de decomposição em números primos e, também, uma outra que permite que você conte até a raiz quadrada do número. Vou entrar em mais detalhes nessa última.

Todo número `X % Y = 0` significa que existe `F` inteiro tal que `F * Y = X`. Para qualquer outro número diferente da raiz quadrada perfeita de `X`, achar `Y` significa saber da existência de seu fator irmão `F`. Se eu assumir que `Y` é menor que `F`, então só preciso contar quantos `Y`s distintos existe no intervalo `[1, raiz(X))` (deixei o intervalo aberto na raiz quadrada, depois explico porquê) e multiplicar por 2. No caso da raiz quadrada, se o número encontrado for um quadrado perfeito, o par de `raiz(X)` será `F = raiz(X)`, então esse número em especial só pode entrar uma vez.

O caso do número `1` e de `X` são divisores triviais, então nem vou passar por eles no laço

```
var divisores_encontrados, r, entrada, divisor_teste: inteiro
início
    leia(entrada)

    se entrada = 1 # único caso que existem menos de dois divisores
        divisores_encontrados = 1
    senão
        divisores_encontrados <- 2 # os dois triviais
         r <- arredonda_baixo(raiz(entrada))
         divisor_teste <- 2
         enquanto divisor_teste < r # não pode ser <= porque o intervalo é aberto na raiz
             se entrada % divisor_teste = 0
                 divisores_encontrados <- divisores_encontrados + 2 # lembrando que achamos divisor_teste e sabemos que ele tem um par F maior do que a raiz quadrada
             fimse
             divisor_teste <- divisor_teste + 1
          fimenquanto

          se entrada % r = 0
             divisores_encontrados <- divisores_encontrados + 1 # entrada é quadrado perfeito
        fimse
    fimse

    escreva(entrada)
    escreva(" possui ")
    escreva(divisores_encontrados)
    escreval(" divisores")
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Muito,muito obrigado pelas explicações, elas foram de suma importância.
Amanhã vou testar o código com mais calma e dou um feedback se funcionou.

abraço e sucesso!

Comment: Excelente resposta! Ajudou na minha dúvida!