# Onde esta o erro desse codigo?

Tags: c

Exercicio: Faça um procedimento que retorna, por parâmetro, um vetor A(5) com os 5 primeiros
números perfeitos.

Meu Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5

void numeros_perfeitos(int A[]) {

    int cont = 0;
    int x, n = 1, soma;

    while (cont < TAM) {
        soma = 0;
        for (x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
            if (n % x == 0 && x != n) {
                soma += x;
            }
        }

        if (soma == n) {
            A[cont] = n;
            cont++;
        }

        n++;
    }
}   

int main () {

    int A[TAM];
    int cont;

    numeros_perfeitos(A);

    printf("Os primeiros cincos números perfeitos são: \n");

    for (cont = 0; cont < TAM; cont++) {
        printf("%d\n",A[cont]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A gente não sabe o que ele deveria fazer, o que está acontecendo. Coloque mais detalhes pra ajudar nós ajudarmos você.

Comment: Ela não está compilando, tem algum erro na logica da função que eu não estou conseguindo identificar

Comment: Se não está compilando ele deve estar mostrando um erro pra você...

Comment: Não mostra nenhum erro porque não é na sintaxe, é na lógica, ai tipo eu executo ele mais não mostra nada.

Comment: Então ele está compilando

Comment: Se não está compilando tem muito mais que erro de lógica. E tem que mostrar erro. Eu dei uma melhorada do código, mas não vi erros nele. Eu só diminui pra 3 porque o ideone tem limite tempo para executar e é um algoritmo pesado. http://ideone.com/tYfIHx

Comment: Cara eu troquei agora aqui no meu código só o numero da constante TAM pra 3 ai funcionou tambem, era só isso que tava dando erro mesmo pq tava pesado o codigo, valeu cara !

Comment: @BrunoEsteves mas em um compilador normal não é pra acontecer isso, o ideone é uma VM pública e não pode deixar rodar qualquer tempo. Com 4 quase deu. De qualquer forma é exponencial, com 5 deve levar minutos, com 6, horas ou dias, 7 ou 8 vai até o computador pifar :)

Answer (score 1):

> Estava procurando aqui um algoritmo que usasse os fatores primos do número para determinar se ele é perfeito ou não, porém não encontrei algo relacionado. Deve ser porque fatorar e calcular os divisores force a solução a criar uma quantidade combinatória de números.

## Números perfeitos

Um número é dito perfeito se a soma de seus divisores próprios for ele mesmo.

O que é um divisor próprio? Para um número `n`, qualquer `d != n` tal que `d > 0, d | n` é um divisor próprio de `n`. 1 não possui divisores próprios; 2 possui apenas 1 como divisor próprio; 6 possui 1, 2 e 3 como divisores próprios.

### Classe de dificuldade do problema

Um ponto de interesse para saber se uma solução vai retornar resultado e qual o tempo esperado que ela retorne o resultado é saber qual a classe de dificuldade do problema.

Aos poucos. A classificação clássica (P, NP, PSPACE, RE e família) é sobre problemas de decisão, que são aqueles problemas cujas respostas admissíveis são **sim** ou **não**. O problema **perfeição de número** se encaixa nessa definição, pois o número é perfeito ou não é perfeito.

Existem diversas formas de classificar os problemas, muitas delas são relacionadas ao tipo de computação/poder computacional usada para resolvê-lo:

- **limitação de tempo de execução**

  - a classe P implica que existe solução que roda em tempo (até) polinomial para o problema de entrada de tamanho `n`, ou seja, tempo de execução em `o(n^p)`;
  - a classe EXP implica que existe solução que roda em tempo (até) exponencial para o problema de entrada de tamanho `n`, ou seja, tempo de execução `o(e^(n^p))`; P pertence a EXP, pois `o(n^p) < o(e^n) < o(e^(n^p))`;
- **limitação de espaço de memória disponível**

  - a classe PSPACE implica que, para uma entrada de tamanho `n`, existe solução que exige no máximo `o(n^p)` memória extra de trabalho; a classe P está contida de maneira própria dentro de PSPACE; PSPACE está contido dentro de EXP (se puder colocar em toda posição X símbolos distintos, percorrer todas as combinações na memória ocupa tempo `X^(o(n^p)) = o(e^(n^p))`)
- **limitação pelo determinismo**

  - a classe P é relativa ao problemas que são resolvidos em tempo polinomial por um algoritmo determinístico;
  - a classe NP é relativa ao problemas que são resolvidos em tempo polinomial por um algoritmo não determinístico;

Uma característica da classe NP é que é possível simular uma operação não determinística dado o problema é, também, uma *dica* de qual o próximo passo a seguir na hora do não determinismo. A essa *dica* dá-se o nome de **certificado**. Para simular um poder computacional NP, precisamos entregar um certificado com, no máximo, um símbolo para cada passo de computação; ou seja, o tamanho máximo do certificado é `o(n^p)`, onde `n` é o tamanho da entrada.

Dada a entrada e um certificado para ela, precisamos de um algoritmo determinístico para provar que a resposta está correta. Dado isso, conseguimos provar que um problema é NP.

Pensei no seguinte certificado para o problema do número perfeito:
- fatores primos e suas multiplicidades (por exemplo: entrada 496, fatores primos [2,4] ; [31,1])
- os `o(n^0.5)` divisores de `n` (valor esse que é idêntico ao produto das multiplicidades dos primos + 1; para 496, temos (4+1) x (2 + 1) = 10 divisores)

> Sobre quantidade de números divisores, tem [uma nota nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209275/64969) que tem a prova de que é `o(2 * n^0.5) ==> o(n^0.5)` para um número `n`

O tamanho desse certificado é polinomial, então o primeiro quesito foi satisfeito. Para verificar que o certificado é válido, temos os seguintes passos:

- somar os supostos divisores e garantir que o resultado é `2n`, pois a soma dos divisores próprios é `n` e o próprio `n` também entrou na lista de divisores passadas
- garantir que a quantidade de divisores siga a fórmula de produto das multiplicidades + 1; verificação essa feita rapidamente
- garantir que todos os supostos divisores são divisores de fato
- dividir o número pelos seus fatores primos e obter 1 no final

Com isso, temos que o certificado é válido e o número com esse certificado é perfeito. Infelizmente, não sei dizer qual a complexidade da divisão, mas creio que seja [quadrática](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations). Assim, nesse caso, temos que o tempo de execução do algoritmo que valida o certificado é polinomial também.

Não consigo provar que o problema é P, entretanto. Se NP != P, e esse problema não for P, então não conseguimos resolver em tempo polinomial, mas podemos tentar diminuir a quantidade de operações realizadas.

## Algoritmo para achar todos os divisores

Para achar a quantidade de divisores de um número, precisamos percorrer de 2 até a raiz quadrada do número (conforme demonstrado nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209275/64969)). 1 já é divisor de qualquer número, então não é preciso computá-lo. Para cada número `D` divisor encontrado, temos `N/D` como o outro divisor. Fazendo uma vez a operação de divisão e armazenando o quociente e o resto, podemos verificar se o número é divisor mesmo e, diferentemente do exemplo, somar os dois fatores irmãos. Só lembrando que o caso de raiz quadrada inteira só conta uma vez como divisor.

### Em C

```
int soma_divisores(int n) {
  int sq = sqrt(n);
  int i;
  int f;
  int soma = 1; // 1 divide todo mundo
  for (i = 2; i < sq; i++) {
    // se achei um número divisor, achei outro também 
    if (n % i == 0) {
      f = n/i;
      soma += f + i;
    }
  }

  // testando se é quadrado perfeito
  if (sq * sq == n) {
    soma += sq;
  }

  return soma;
}
```

Como o espaço de busca dos divisores foi bruscamente partido, esse código deverá rodar muito mais rapidamente na sua máquina.

Answer (score 0):

O erro esta no while ele nao roda pois sempre é menor que zero tente mudar